# Text in circle in circular motion

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to create a textview with a circular background such as shown in the image below. I have 6 other circles like this as well which come from user input.

[image]

However I run into problems if there are too many characters, it breaks the boundaries of the circle. I want to make the text go in a circular motion around the circle if the text is more than lets say 10 characters like this.

[image]

I've read other people have the same problem and the answers revolved around creating custom views. I am not that experienced with Java yet so if anyone can guide me through this I would really appreciate it.